# Write value to specific excel Cell after checking condition

Tags: excel

I have a file in excel thats contains in one column many tagnumbers of instruments.
We also have an other file with two columns, this file is a data extraction of many AutoCad files and contains a tagnumber in the first column and the title of the document it was found in the second column.

By checking the tagnumbers in both files, if they are the same I want to write the information from the second column of one file into a specific column in the other file.

Could somebody point me in the right direction? Maybe a good search term on Google?

Comment: I think  a simple vlookup function will do. Do you want to populate the 2nd column of the 1st file?

Comment: I want to populate a specifc column in the 1st file. I will look into vlookup.

Comment: Great! If you will encounter problems, don't hesitate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for can be done with the excel function `Vlookup`. Visit this link to understand how to use it: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1